# In Javascript: given a non-negative integer, return an array or a list of the individual digits in order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help with this question:

Given a non-negative integer, return an array or a list of the individual digits in order.

Specification: 
- digitize(n)
- separate multiple digit numbers into an array

Parameters
n: Number - Number to be converted

Return Value:
Array - Array of separated single digit integers

Examples:

```
n       Return Value
123     [1,2,3]
8675309 [8,6,7,5,3,0,9]
```

Comment: Share your attempt. Seems to be a homework.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var n = 123987;
var arr = n.toString(10).replace(/\D/g, '0').split('').map(Number);
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = arr;
```

```html
<div id="abc">
</div>
```